# How to remove new line from .txt file and then store it to std::vector<std::string>?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this `name_and_id.txt` file which contains User Names and their IDs.

The file contains:

```
Heal: A24-1234
Hael: A25-4567
Hela: A26-8910
Hale: A27-1112

Test1: A28-1314
Test2: A29-1516
Test3: A30-1718
```

What I want to do is to remove the `new line` first before I store this text in `std::vector<std::string>`

My code looks like this and it tokenize the texts first, but there's still `new line` in the output

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

auto main() -> int {
  
    std::fstream user_file{};
    
    const char space_char{' '}; //NOTE - space delimiter 
    std::string entries_by_line{};
    std::vector<std::string> data_entries{};
    
    std::stringstream entries_in_file{};
    
    std::string entries_data_imported_file{};
    std::vector<std::string> tokenized_data_imported_file{};
  
    user_file.open("name_and_id.txt");
    if(user_file.is_open()) {
        while(std::getline(user_file, entries_by_line)) { 
            data_entries.emplace_back(entries_by_line); //REVIEW - store data (without new lines) from `.txt` file into vector named `data_entries`
        }
  
        std::copy(
            data_entries.begin(),
            data_entries.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(entries_in_file, " ") //REVIEW - copy contents (with spaces) of vector `data_entries` to a std::stringstream named `entries_in_file`
        );
    
        std::cout << "Before removing punctuations:" << std::endl;
        for(size_t i{}; i != data_entries.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << data_entries[i] << std::endl;
        }
  
        std::stringstream entries{std::move(entries_in_file.str())}; //REVIEW - store content of entries_in_file.str() to std::stringstream named `entries`
    
        while(std::getline(entries, entries_data_imported_file, space_char)) {
            entries_data_imported_file.erase(
                std::remove_if(
                    entries_data_imported_file.begin(),
                    entries_data_imported_file.end(),
                    ispunct //REVIEW - remove punctuations
                ),
                entries_data_imported_file.end()
            );
            tokenized_data_imported_file.emplace_back(entries_data_imported_file); //REVIEW - store data (without punctuations) to vector `tokenized_data_imported_file`
        }
        
    
        std::cout << "\nAfter removing punctuations:" << std::endl;
        for(size_t i{}; i != tokenized_data_imported_file.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << tokenized_data_imported_file[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    user_file.close();
  
}
```

Output:

```
Before removing punctuations:
Heal: A24-1234
Hael: A25-4567
Hela: A26-8910
Hale: A27-1112

Test1: A28-1314
Test2: A29-1516
Test3: A30-1718

After removing punctuations and new line:
Heal
A241234
Hael
A254567
Hela
A268910
Hale
A271112

Test1
A281314
Test2
A291516
Test3
A301718
```

What can I do to remove the `new line`?

Comment: `if (!entries_by_line.empty()) data_entries.emplace_back(entries_by_line)`?

Comment: Why do you need both `entries_in_file` and `entries`? Aren't they just a copy of each other?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude O... it's copy of each other, thank you for that.